# Unity web player API?

Tags: unity, graphics

Just curious about it. I only want to know that what graphics API does the Unity web player uses. Is that WEBGL? Or simply OPENGL? Or A custom one? Then how do the games get gpu acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

There's the Unity Web Player, which is enabled by a Browser-Plugin, similar to Flash. The Web Player supports almost all features of the Unity-Engine, with the exception of some Plugins and Filesystem access.

In addition to this, there's also the possibility to export the game to HTML5/WebGL. It's possible that some features of your game won't work in some browsers when choosing this mode ([Browser compatibility matrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html)). The advantage of WebGL is, that it works without any Plugins (given your Browser supports the required web-technologies, such as WebGL and Web Audio).

As to what API the different implementations use: If you're using the Unity Web Player, the API will be determined by the Web Player Plugin. It will use OpenGL or DirectX, depending on Platform. 
WebGL is also an abstract wrapper for the graphics API… most commonly it will use OpenGL, but some browsers use DirectX on Windows (also see [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867040/under-windows-webgl-makes-use-of-directx-runtime-or-opengl-runtime)).